# calling wordpress page from react

Tags: wordpress

How do I call a wordpress page from react component. Earlier, I had this in a wordpress page (from template file) say homepage

```
 <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a
                              href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'search-results' ) ); ?>"
                              class="theme-btn w-100 text-center margin-top-20px" onclick="FrontPage.setValuesForExtendedSearch()"
                              >Search Now</a
                            >
                          </div>
```

And clicking on the button was working fine and going to the target page

Now,  I changed that homepage to be served form react component. The page is serving fine.But I am unable to figure out a way to replace my above code so it can call another page like it was doing before. How do I achieve this.

I am looking for an overall approach to do this . Are there any third party tools that I need to work with when working with react in wordpress?  to be able to make it a bit easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I thought over it , it occurred to me that calling a wordpress page from react is not needed because I may not need to go to a different wordpress page . I have implemented React router and included the top level html divs in homepage itself and convert the lower level rest of the html into react and render it on top level divs. As per my understanding, React is for that use case ( ex: single page apps) .  I think this is the way forward that I see , at least at this point of time and per my understanding.

Approuter.js

```
 export const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <div >

            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePageFlightContainer/>} /> 
                <Route path="/search" element={<RenderTopMenuResultPage />} />
            </Routes>

        </div>
    );
};
```

and index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRouter /> ,  <HomePageFlightContainer />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('search-flights-container')
   
)
```

RenderTopMenuResultPage.js

```
export const RenderTopMenuResultPage = (props) => {
    return (
   <>
    {
        createPortal(
            <CreateTopMenuResultPage/>,
            document.getElementById('result-page-sort-menu')
        )
    }
</>
);
```

};

`result-page-sort-menu` and `search-flights-container` are on wordpress homepage , which is built from template ( so they are in template actually)